# Windows 10 freezes randomly

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

``hey folks! I have been getting these random freezes for a couple of times now where my whole system gets locked up and stays like that for an indefinite amount of time unless I do a hard manual restart from outside.
Here's what I found after I checked the windows reliability history:

```
Problem Event Name: LiveKernelEvent
Code:   141
Parameter 1:    ffffe000a8024010
Parameter 2:    fffff801f2565d4c
Parameter 3:    0
Parameter 4:    31c
OS version: 10_0_10240
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    256_1
OS Version: 10.0.10240.2.0.0.256.4
Locale ID:  1033
```

Comment: Your title says Windows 10, your tags say Windows 7. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that would bring more people to my question.